# Can i have a mongoose model that refers itself?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a model that looks like this

```
    const employeeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    empFirstName:{
        type: String,
        reuired: true
    },
    empLastName:{
        type: String,
        reuired: true
    },
    empEmail:{
        type: String,
        reuired: true
    },
    empPassword:{
        type: String,
        reuired: true
    },
    empConfirmPass:{
        type: String,
        reuired: true
    },
    empContactNum:{
        type: Number,
        reuired: true
    },  
    empPosition:{
        type: String,
        reuired: true
    },
    empTeam:{
        type: String,
        reuired: true
    }
});
const Employee = mongoose.model('EMPLOYEE', employeeSchema);

module.exports = Employee;
```

1. I'm trying to have another field named "mentor" in the employee model, who will again be an employee (a user from employee model) , so how do I make a model refer itself?

i want something like this

```
    mentor :[{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Employee'
  }]
```

Does this work?
what is the correct way to do this?

2. also I wanted a teamMembers field which will be an array of 0 or more employees from employee model

how do i do this?

Comment: `Does this work?` Try it and you'll find out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work. You had it correct in your question:

```
const employeeSchema = new Schema ({
  mentor: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Employee' }],
  teamMembers: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Employee' }],
})
```

I've added some routes as well just to give you an idea on how to use it.

```
// add team member to employee
index.post('/addTeamMember', (req, res) => {
  Employee.findById(req.body.employeeId, (err, employee) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      employee.teamMembers.push(req.body.teamMemberId);
      employee.save((err) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          res.redirect('/');
        }
      });
    }
  });
});

// add mentor to employee
index.post('/addMentor', (req, res) => {
  Employee.findById(req.body.employeeId, (err, employee) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      employee.mentor.push(req.body.mentorId);
      employee.save((err) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          res.redirect('/');
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

You can also `populate` those fields:

```
index.get('/populate', (req, res) => {
  Employee.findById(req.body.employeeId)
    .populate('mentor')
    .populate('teamMembers')
    .exec((err, employee) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        res.send(employee);
      }
    });
});
```

and just some suggestions:

1. Don't name your fields `emFirstName`, `emLastName`, etc. This is redundant as you already have your model named Employee. It also makes your code less legible. Instead just use `firstName`, `lastName`, etc.
2. I wouldn't recommend using all caps for a model name like `'EMPLOYEE'` as this is not the recommended case for mongoose model names. They suggest upercase first letter, so `Employee` would be more correct.

Comment: Thanks for helping me with the routes as well. That worked!! @Dylan